# mysqli update query uncaught exception

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update data in a DB using this code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

require("../db_connect.php");

if ($_GET['action'] == 'insert')

{

$query = "INSERT INTO tblfatture_2019 (id_booking, IdPaese, IdCodice, CodiceFiscale, Denominazione, Cognome, Nome, Indirizzo, NumeroCivico, CAP, Comune, Provincia, Nazione, payment_method, date_fattura, pre_paid, CodiceDestinatario, PECDestinatario) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

$var1 = $_GET['id_booking'];
$var2 = $_GET['IdPaese'];
$var3 = $_GET['IdCodice'];
$var4 = $_GET['CodiceFiscale'];
$var5 = $_GET['Denominazione'];
$var6 = $_GET['Cognome'];
$var7 = $_GET['Nome'];
$var8 = $_GET['Indirizzo'];
$var9 = $_GET['NumeroCivico'];
$var10 = $_GET['CAP'];
$var11 = $_GET['Comune'];
$var12 = $_GET['Provincia'];
$var13 = $_GET['Nazione'];
$var14 = $_GET['payment_method'];
$var15 = $_GET['date_fattura'];
$var16 = $_GET['pre_paid'];
$var17 = $_GET['CodiceDestinatario'];
$var18 = $_GET['PECDestinatario'];

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"issssssssssssssdss", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9, $var10, $var11, $var12, $var13, $var14, $var15, $var16, $var17, $var18);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}

else if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete') 

{

$val1 = $_GET['id_fattura'];

$query = "DELETE FROM tblfatture_2019 WHERE id_fattura = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $val1);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   


}

else

{

$query = "UPDATE tblfatture_2019 SET id_booking=?, IdPaese=?, IdCodice=?, CodiceFiscale=?, Denominazione=?, Cognome=?, Nome=?, Indirizzo=?, NumeroCivico=?, CAP=?, Comune=?, Provincia=?, Nazione=?, payment_method=?, date_fattura=?, pre_paid=?, CodiceDestinatario=?, PECDestinatario=? WHERE id_fattura=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

$var1 = $_GET['id_booking'];
$var2 = $_GET['IdPaese'];
$var3 = $_GET['IdCodice'];
$var4 = $_GET['CodiceFiscale'];
$var5 = $_GET['Denominazione'];
$var6 = $_GET['Cognome'];
$var7 = $_GET['Nome'];
$var8 = $_GET['Indirizzo'];
$var9 = $_GET['NumeroCivico'];
$var10 = $_GET['CAP'];
$var11 = $_GET['Comune'];
$var12 = $_GET['Provincia'];
$var13 = $_GET['Nazione'];
$var14 = $_GET['payment_method'];
$var15 = $_GET['date_fattura'];
$var16 = $_GET['pre_paid'];
$var17 = $_GET['CodiceDestinatario'];
$var18 = $_GET['PECDestinatario'];
$val19 = $_GET['id_fattura'];

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'issssssssssssssdssi', $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9, $var10, $var11, $var12, $var13, $var14, $var15, $var16, $var17, $var18, $var19);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

but I'm getting errors, the latest one being:

I have been trying to debug for hours now and can't understand why the update query does not work when the related `insert` and 'delete' statement work like a charm as well as several other `update` statements that I am using.

I have alrerady tried to enclose the table and column names between both ` and ' marks but it did not help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest you to show an example of a working `update` query. May be once you take a closer look on the differences between the two, you even understand the issue yourself. Best regards

Comment: I have a db with 30 tables and many updates query which are working perfectly fine. I have compared, compared and compared... but can not understand why this very one is not working.

Comment: If you think it is helpful, I can post the related insert query which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You already calling the database with the unfinished query at:

```
 if (!$con->query($query)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
 }
```

Try removing that. `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` already executes the query later, so there's even no need for this.

Have a close look at the examples given by the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Have some checks: are the database columns the proper type? What happens if you try updating the db manually with the same sql, but with the values inserted? What returns the `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)` after the execute method? Is the connection `$con` ok, since it's not in the question's code?

Comment: You could also try and take the example from the docs and edit the db, variables etc. and see if that works

Comment: UPDATE `tblfatture_2019` SET `id_booking`=1041,`Denominazione`='test',`payment_method`='contanti',`Indirizzo`='Loc Sa Leo',`NumeroCivico`='108',`CAP`='52031',`Comune`='Anghiari',`Provincia`='AR',`Nazione`='IT',`Cognome`='',`Nome`='',`pre_paid`=100,`IdPaese`='IT',`IdCodice`='12345678910',`CodiceDestinatario`='0000123',`PECDestinatario`='pec@pec.it',`CodiceFiscale`='ABCDEF12345A123A',`date_fattura`='2018-10-29' WHERE `id_fattura`=23

Comment: The SQL is good, but what happens if you manually execute that on the MySQL server? (Using phpMyAdmin or something like that)

Comment: Did you set error reporting on and what does it give back as error? And what does `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)` return after the execute function? (This will be 0 if the sent values are the same as already in the DB.)

Comment: I have set mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); at the beginning of my page and mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) after the execute function. Both do not return anything I can see.

Comment: Try the PHP error reporting by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top. They might give some errors regarding your php

Comment: Thanks for your patience... I did what you said but it is still not returning anything.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question to what it is now?

Comment: You're not outputting `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)` result, try `echo 'Return: ' . mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt); exit();` and tell me what it prints out

Comment: It returns: 0, when I try to modify at least one of the variables.

Comment: My only guess is that the new value might already by like that in the database row. Maybe there's a duplicate row with the same `id_fattura`? Otherwise, I don't know

Comment: Unfortunately not... the new value is different from the old one and id_fattura is the primary key allowing no duplicates. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could try copying another working update sequence and edited that. Sort of 'start from new' approach. Hopefully you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

A spelling mistake $val19 = $_GET['id_fattura']; instead of $var19 = $_GET['id_fattura']; which kept me busy and drove me crazy for almost a week...